# Replace variables extracted from database with theirs values

Tags: mysql, perl, variables, cgi

I'd like to translate a perl web site in several languages. I search for and tried many ideas, but I think the best one is to save all translations inside the mySQL database. But I get a problem...

When a sentence extracted from the database contains a variable (scalar), it prints on the web page as a scalar:

```
You have $number new messages.
```

Is there a proper way to reassign `$number` its actual value ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: This is not a simple matter of just filling in placeholder text. In many languages, other parts of the sentence will also change depending on the value of the placeholder. For example, "You have 0 new messag*es*." vs. "You have 1 new messag*e*." Other languages have different rules.

Comment: Thank you for your remark but I can manage that in the database. For example in english **You have $number new messages** and in french **$number nouveaux messages en attente**. But I cannot print the value of `$number`...

Comment: [It's not that simple.](http://search.cpan.org/~ferreira/Locale-Maketext-1.13/lib/Locale/Maketext/TPJ13.pod#A_Localization_Horror_Story:_It_Could_Happen_To_You) (That article is a bit out-of-date but the description of the problem is still accurate. Also see [On the state of i18n in Perl](http://rassie.org/archives/247).)

Comment: Thank you again but if someone can help me with the specific question asked above ?...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `printf` format strings in your database and pass in values to that.
`printf` allows you to specify the position of the argument so only have know what position with the list of parameters "$number" is.

For example

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $Details = {
   'Name' => 'Mr Satch',
   'Age'  => '31',
   'LocationEn' => 'England',
   'LocationFr' => 'Angleterre',
   'NewMessages' => 20,
   'OldMessages' => 120,
};

my $English = q(
 Hello %1$s, I see you are %2$s years old and from %3$s
 How are you today?
 You have %5$i new messages and %6$i old messages
 Have a nice day
);
my $French = q{
 Bonjour %1$s, je vous vois d'%4$s et âgés de %2$s ans.
 Comment allez-vous aujourd'hui?
 Vous avez %5$i nouveaux messages et %6$i anciens messages.
 Bonne journée.
};
printf($English, @$Details{qw/Name Age LocationEn LocationFr NewMessages OldMessages/});
printf($French,  @$Details{qw/Name Age LocationEn LocationFr NewMessages OldMessages/});
```

This would be a nightmare to maintain so an alternative might be to include an argument list in the database:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

sub fetch_row {
   return { 
      'Format' => 'You have %i new messages and %i old messages' . "\n",
      'Arguments'  => 'NewMessages OldMessages',
   }
}

sub PrintMessage {
    my ($info,$row) = @_;
    printf($row->{'Format'},@$info{split(/ +/,$row->{'Arguments'})});
}

my $Details = {
   'Name' => 'Mr Satch',
   'Age'  => '31',
   'LocationEn' => 'England',
   'LocationFr' => 'Angleterre',
   'NewMessages' => 20,
   'OldMessages' => 120,
};

my $row = fetch_row();
PrintMessage($Details,$row)
```

Comment: Great solution ! Thank you so much !!

Comment: You're asking that the OP alters their entire database to support `printf` formats. I don't think that's a great answer